# Where to find XP driver for "NATPC M7" android tablet

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, android

I have just purchased a NATPC M7 8GB 7" Google Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) Tablet PC.

If I look under "Model number" within Settings-phone status I see it says "MID_Serials".

I have no idea how to find a driver for it for Windows XP. Might it not even exist?

EDIT: The phone is [here on amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/M7-Gingerbread-Multi-Touch-CAPACITIVE-supports/dp/B004S61EPC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1328287302&sr=8-1).

EDIT: The phone is also known as the Tabtech M7

Answer (score 0):

You need the latest [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: I have both - but now what do I do to connect my tablet to my pc?

Comment: Connect it via USB. It will be recognized. What is your goal by connecting it?

Comment: debugging my app

Comment: Use the SDK tools, they will be able to communicate with the device. You can find the android debug bridge tool in <sdk>/platform-tools/ [adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

Comment: I just did "adb devices" but the resulting list was empty. Just to check I tried connecting my samsung phone and that was listed.

Comment: I also tried simply "adb logcat" and ran my app - but I nothing appeared in the adb window.